# Expect-CT header per lighthouse

Tags: lighthouse

When I run lighthouse, I'm told the following:

```
Deprecated Feature Used
The Expect-CT header is deprecated and will be removed. Chrome requires Certificate Transparency for all publicly trusted certificates issued after April 30, 2018.
```

It tells me that one resource is affected, and it's the font-awesome css that I'm loading.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.0/css/all.css">
```

Is the way that I'm loading this file the cause for this error?